# Google Analytics: Connect Search Term and Event

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

Goal: Connect a send button on a website with a Google Analytics event, and then show in GA what query brought the users who clicked the button to the website. 
How far I got: 
In GA I can see a list of queries under Acquisition > Search Enginge Optimization > Queries that brought users to the website. 
Also, when I go to Behaviour > Events > Event Flow, I can see the number of triggered events, so the website button is correctly connected to GA. (I followed these instructions: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events Also, analytics.js is embedded on every page of the website according to these instructions: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/). When I select "Source / Medium" in the dropdown menu at the mentioned GA Event Flow view, I can even see the number of users who came to the website via "google / organic" and then triggered the event. But I can't see which queries brought those users to the website. So, is there any way I can see this information?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's been a while, here are some solutions that might not be the best, but would work:

**Segments**

Create a segment based on the event you want to get data from (Maybe an event category or label). Then view the report you'd like to get data on (such as the Query report). Then this report will be queries for people arriving at the site who have triggered that particular event.

---

**Dashboard**

Create a custom dashboard with the dimensions and metrics you're looking into, then apply a filter to that specific dashboard widget.

---

**Custom Report**

Under the Customization tab, create a custom report with the data you're looking into, and apply a filter to it specifically.

---

Again, these aren't perfect because you'd either have to create or edit these constantly if you're trying to check lots of different events.

You could also consider using custom dimensions that are scoped to the session along with your events- then you could view the Queries report and add a secondary dimension of your custom dimension.